# Python stream audio from YouTube livestream

Tags: python-3.x, pafy, python-vlc

I'm interested in creating a python 3.9 program that streams audio from a YouTube livestream but unfortunately I can't get the `video.getbestaudio()` function to work and the function only returns the value null. Thus causing the null error on the next line.

Just in case you need to know I'm using the Pafy library to get the audio stream and the python-vlc library to play the audio. The script is also fully functional if I use a YouTube video that is not a livestream or use the `video.getbest()` function but this also creates a window displaying the video stream which is not what I want.

I was wondering how I could work around the error and create a functioning python script. I am open to use other methods if they properly work. Thanks for any help in advance!

**Here is the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mjten\Desktop\Programing\Python\lofi.py", line 8, in <module>
    playurl = best.url
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'
```

**Here is my code:**

```
import pafy
import vlc

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A'

video = pafy.new(url)                                                                                                                       
best = video.getbestaudio()                                                                                                                 
playurl = best.url                                                                                                                          
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(playurl)                                                                                                           
player.play()

while True: pass
```

P.S Sorry for the bad code I'm just trying to figure out a working example in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

pip install pafy

pip install youtube_dl

```
import pafy

def stream(url):
   video = pafy.new(url, ydl_opts={'nocheckcertificate': True})
    print(video)
    best = video.getbestaudio()
    stream_urls = best.url
    print(stream_urls)


stream('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A')
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this still returns a null error and unfortunately does not work on live streams.